# Conditionally independent sequence that is elementwise conditionally dependent

Tags: probability, independence

We have a sequence of discrete random variables $\boldsymbol x = \{x_1,\dots,x_n\} \in \mathcal X^n$ and a discrete conditional $P_{Y|X}$, i.e.

$$p(\boldsymbol y | \boldsymbol x) = \prod_i p(y_i|x_i). $$

If we assume that for all $p(\boldsymbol y | \boldsymbol x)>0$, we have $p(\boldsymbol y | \boldsymbol x) = f(x_1,\dots, x_n)g(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ which roughly means that we can't infer anything about $\boldsymbol x$ based on $\boldsymbol y$ besides the fact that $p(\boldsymbol y | \boldsymbol x)>0$.

I'm trying to come up with an example of a memoryless transformation such that that whenever $p(\boldsymbol y | \boldsymbol x) >0$ we have

$$\prod_i p(y_i|x_i) = f(\boldsymbol x)g(\boldsymbol y),$$

but $p(y_i|x_i) = h(y_i,x_i)$. That is, all *possible* input sequences $\boldsymbol x$ are equally likely given $\boldsymbol y$, but for some element pair $(x_i,y_i)$ we have $p(x_i|y_i)> p(x_i'|y_i)$.

Apologies if this is ill defined as stated, will try to clear up if more information is needed.

EDIT: Actually, what we can say is that whenever $p(\boldsymbol y | \boldsymbol x) >0$ we have

$$\prod_i p(y_i|x_i) = f(\boldsymbol y).$$

What we want to know is if this implies $p(y_i|x_i) = g(x_i)h(y_i)$.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand, why $p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{x})g(\mathbf{y})$?

Comment: It just means that the conditional pdf is a product distribution.

Comment: can you write the proof? because i think, it is a bit strange, if your formula is right, then we will have $p(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=[f(\mathbf{x})]^2 g(\mathbf{y})$

Comment: $f(\boldsymbol x)$ isn't necessarily the pdf, I'm just saying that the conditional pdf factorizes in SOME manner.

Comment: ah I see, then $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are (automatically) independent, right?

Comment: They are independent for all pairs such that $p(\boldsymbol x|\boldsymbol y)>0$. Actually we can refine the assumptions slightly, let me edit.